# Google Distance Matrix - Limit country

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Distance Matrix API to look up distances from two locations.  I need to limit the search to the UK as I am having problems where if you search an incomplete postcode i.e. 'L20', Google instantly suggests an 'L20' area in the USA which obviously causes the search to obtain no results.

How do I limit the Google's search criteria to a specific country/region?

This is my current code:

```
function dist($addr, $addr2) {
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=' . urlencode ( $addr ) . '&destinations=' . urlencode ( $addr2 ) . '&key=';
    return getCachableContent ( $url );
}
```

Comment: Try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234975/how-to-restrict-google-map-api-to-find-places-within-a-specific-country-and-city / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956511/google-geocodeing-api-search-in-just-one-country

Comment: @d.datul1990 unfortunately they are for map api, not distance matrix, i have tried them but they dont see to work.

Comment: @Deckerz I'm having the same problem.  Did you every find a solution?

Comment: Added a potential solution below.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Google Geocoding API along with the Google Distance Matrix API as part of the solution. The Geocoding API will be able to provide country information for a given address (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start for example Google Geocoding API output).

Firstly you would pass the addresses to the Geocoding API to determine if the address has a country value of, in your case, the UK. If yes then proceed to pass the values to the Distance API.

**UPDATE 1: Sample Code based on your original code**

Taking your original code:

```
function dist($addr, $addr2) {
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=' . urlencode ( $addr ) . '&destinations=' . urlencode ( $addr2 ) . '&key=';
    return getCachableContent ( $url );
}
```

it may look something like this:

```
function dist($addr, $addr2) {
    $geocodeurl1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode ( $addr ) . '&key=';        

    $geocodeurl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode ( $addr2 ) . '&key=';

    //Then do some checking here to see if the country values for both returns above are UK based (e.g. if statements). If both are UK then proceed to perform your original call to the distancematrix  
    $distanceurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=' . urlencode ( $addr ) . '&destinations=' . urlencode ( $addr2 ) . '&key=';
    return getCachableContent ( $distanceurl );
}
```